# How to solve Robots.txt problem with WordPress fresh install?

Tags: seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, robots.txt

I installed a fresh copy of WordPress few weeks ago and I have been having some strange problems.

1- I get this message : "Comments for FirstName LastName
name-last.com/‎
A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more."
When I google my name. I re-checked setting and I haven't checked the "discourage option"

2- I installed WP Better Security and Yoast SEO plugin. Now I have another problem!

When I google my domain RANDOM Web Sniffing Websites come up that exposes my data server and many more thing!

Where did I go wrong ?

PS: My robots.txt is fixed to disallow only Plugin Folder since yesterday (not too long)

Comment: Are your privacy settings correct?

Comment: by privacy you mean my .htaccess file or my setting inside WordPress ?
1- I haven't touched the .ht file, I only created a robot.txt file

2- and for the setting I un-checked the part that says discourage browsers.

Comment: Maybe this question should be migrated to the Webmaster forum?

Comment: Regarding my previous comment - Other than allowing editing of robots.txt I'm not sure Yoast SEO is a cause of the problem and WP Better Security doesn't alter it as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1):

Your robots file as of right now:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: 
User-agent: *
Disallow: 
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Sitemap: http://www.yadfaeq.com
```

You aren't specifying anything for Googlebot so you should remove it. Additionally, `Disallow:` could be interpreted as `Disallow: /` which would block your entire site.

What your robots file should be:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Sitemap: http://www.yadfaeq.com
```

Google often caches the *robots.txt* file so it may take some time for it to check for a new one. I suggest you use [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/) to help control what Google is indexing.

I do not see the changes you said you made to your *robots.txt* file. Perhaps your server is caching it as well?

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate. I started implementing the Webmaster Tools and after that my website gets picked by weird Bots and now the first page of Google is all these websites :-( !
The only problem is, for every change I have to wait for a while.

I think I messed it up.